# reactJs Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code:

```
class MainScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedTab: 'news'
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch({
        type:'isLoggedIn',
        isLoggedIn: false
    })
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate: --------')
    return false;
  }

  navigateToAuthScreen() {
    this.props.navigator.immediatelyResetRouteStack([
      rootRoutes.authScreen
    ]);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps: ----');
    if (!nextProps.isLoggedIn) this.navigateToAuthScreen();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('rending: ----------------------');
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TabBarIOS tintColor={theme.accentColor} translucent>
        <Icon.TabBarItem
          iconName="newspaper-o"
          title="News"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'news'}>
          <SceneStack
            initialRoute={newsRoutes.newsListing}
          />
        </Icon.TabBarItem>
      </TabBarIOS>
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

**update:**

I found out that this error has something to do with TabBarIOS and Icon.TabBarItem somehow.

I've removed `onPress={() => this.switchTabsOrPopStack('news')}` altogether and the error still happened.

**I am getting this error:**

Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the TabBarItem component.

I am not sure what am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with your navigateToAuthScreen() method.

Basically, you change scene in the componentWillReceiveProps lifecycle event, which causes the component to unmount. But React was still going through the lifecycle events and called setState somewhere. I'm not sure how it works under the hood but it seems the unmount is called before it had finished the previous lifecycles up until render().

I had the same warning when using Navigator, I mounted the homescreen before I checked the login state, if I wasn't logged in I would swap to a login screen.

I fixed it by having a splash screen show up on app startup, make sure all my stores and login states etc. were initialized before rendering screens.

Comment: I stuck in the same situation because of navigator can you elaborate how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

There is an extremely quick fix to this somewhat vague error which will give you a full stack trace with the offending component. Just put the following code into your console and attempt to recreate the error:

```
  var warn = console.warn;
  console.warn = function(warning) {
    if (/(setState)/.test(warning)) {
      throw new Error(warning);
    }
    warn.apply(console, arguments);
  };
```

I have a feeling the component presenting the issue with surprise you, I'm fairly sure the issue is not in the code provided, especially since you aren't setting state in the code provided.

Comment: @NetaMeta it did not provide a longer stack trace in the console?

Comment: This works also for React-native? I do not see anything pasting this code in the console browser. Any hint?

Answer (score 2):

i've encountered this error, when using inline functions for the click event like you did.

Please try extracting your onPress-Handler:

```
onPress() {
    this.setState({selectedTab: 'news'});
}
```

And in your onPress:

```
onPress={this.onPress.bind(this)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try returning true for 'shouldComponentUpdate'.

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
console.log('shouldComponentUpdate: --------');
return true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue being discussed on https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3878.

And to display the component name which causing this warning... a solution is given in the following link

https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/3913